# Multiplying two rasterlayers in R

Tags: raster, r

I want to multiply two raster layers. Values of the first layer range from 0 to 5 and values of the second layer range from 5 to 15. It is obvious that I should get some 0 values after multiplication, but MIN value of the output is 5. It means, that 0*5 is returning 5. I want it to return 0. I tried several things, for example:

```
 y3<-y2*y1 
 y3<-overlay(y1,y2,fun=function(x,y){return(x*y)})
```

These return the same thing. I also tried to add arguments `na.rm=TRUE` to the function in second example, but nothing happened.

Comment: How are you getting the min? Since the default for summary statistics is a sample you may just be missing a very low-frequency mininmum. Try something like `min( x[], na.rm=TRUE )` or `cellStats(x, min, asSample=FALSE)`

Comment: In the description of layers, I ve got: for the first:  
     values : 0, 5 (min,max)

and for the second:

     values: 5, 15 (min,max).
After multiplication, final layer has got: 'values : 5, 25 (min,max) '.

Comment: And I also tried your ways, and it is still the same. The first layer for sure contains lots of zeros, but the final layer has got minimum of 5.

Comment: So, are the values changing at all? I have no good theories here other than misalignment (which should throw an error). Can you share your data?

Comment: I can save that as raster asi .grd file and send it to you, I dont know whether its possible to share it here. However, it is calculating well all besides the zeros, cause when I plot the final layer, the result is sensible and I see that for example 5*5 is 25, all the values change besides those where one numerator is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Can you reproduce your situation? Because in my R session all work as expected:

```
library(raster)

#with raster
t <- r <- raster(ncol=100,nrow=100)
r[] <- sample(0:5,10000,replace = T)
t[] <- sample(5:15,10000,replace = T)
s <- t*r

library(terra)
#with terra
rr <- rast(r)
tt <- rast(t)
ss <- rr*tt
```

Here is my output:

```
> s
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 100, 100, 10000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 3.6, 1.8  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0, 75  (min, max)

> ss
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 100, 100, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 3.6, 1.8  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs 
source      : memory 
name        : layer 
min value   :     0 
max value   :    75
```

Also from the plot, I can see pixel where the value are 0. You can try with the `terra` package, but without some reproducible example is hard to help you.